# Questions 4 and 5 from section 4.3 of Conway's complex analysis book

Tags: complex-analysis

I'm reading the [Conway's complex analysis book](https://books.google.com.br/books?id=9LtfZr1snG0C&printsec=frontcover&hl=pt-BR&source=gbs_ge_summary_r&cad=0#v=onepage&q&f=false) and I'm trying to solve theses exercises on page 80:

> 4.Prove that $e^{z+a}=e^ze^a$
>
> 5.Prove that $\cos(a+b)=\cos a\cos b-\sin a\sin b$

The author asks to use the corollary 3.8 which says:

> **Corollary 3.8**: If $f$ and $g$ are analytic on a region $G$ then $f\equiv g$ iff $\{z\in G;f(z)=g(z)\}$ has a limit point in $G$.

My only guess to solve these exercises is to find a limit point of the set $\{z\in G;f(z)=g(z)\}$, where $f$ and $g$ are the RHS and LHS of the equations, but I don't know how to find them.

Just a remark, this is not a homework, as you can see in my last questions I'm using this site to study this book by my own.

Comment: You can show that $f(z) = e^z e^{w-z}$ is constant by differentiating.

Comment: @HenryW yes, but I would like to follow the suggestion of the author.

Comment: What properties of $\exp$ is allowed to use?

Comment: I imagine that we have to use the fact that $e^{2 i n \pi + z}=e^z$ for all $n \in \mathbb N$ and all $z \in \mathbb C$. But I don't see how to transform the sequence $(2 i n \pi)_{n \in \mathbb N}$ into a converging sequence transforming also the equation $e^{z+a}=e^z e^a$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the question about

> Prove that $e^{z+a}=e^{z}e^{a}$

you only need to define two functions, $f(z)=e^{z+a}$ and $g(z)=e^{z}e^{a}$. Both functions are entire, and from real analysis, we know that $f\equiv g$ when $z\in \Bbb{R}$. But since $\Bbb{R}$ has limit points in $\Bbb{C}$, then $f\equiv g$ for all $z\in \Bbb{C}$. The same argument works for the second part of the exercise.