# Equality of analytic functions equal on a diverging sequence of complex

Tags: complex-analysis

I ask this question as a subsequent of [following one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1643390/questions-4-and-5-from-section-4-3-of-conways-complex-analysis-book). Suppose that $f$ and $g$ are two analytic functions defined on $\mathbb C$ and that $(a_n)_{n \in \mathbb N}$ is a sequence of complex numbers such that $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \vert a_n \vert = \infty$ and $f(a_n)=g(a_n)$ for all $n \in \mathbb N$. Is it true that $f=g$?

The answer can be a proof or a counterexample. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint**

Consider any analytic function $f(z).$ Now, define $g(z)=f(z)+\sin z.$ Can you find a divergent sequence $(a_n)$ such that $f(a_n)=g(a_n)?$